# OS X: Make failing due to space in path

Tags: macos, makefile, installation, ffi

I'm trying to install the FFI gem.  The native extensions are not building.  THe problem is in the make.  If I so it manually, here's what I see:

```
RossRankins-MacBook-Pro:libffi Ross$ make
make "AR_FLAGS=" "CC_FOR_BUILD=" "CFLAGS=-g -O2" "CXXFLAGS=" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD="    "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/install -c" "JC1FLAGS=" "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "MAKE=make" "MAKEINFO=/bin/sh "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/missing" --run makeinfo " "PICFLAG=" "PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=" "RUNTESTFLAGS=" "SHELL=/bin/sh" "exec_prefix=/usr/local" "infodir=/usr/local/share/info" "libdir=/usr/local/lib" "prefix=/usr/local" "AR=ar" "AS=as" "CC=gcc" "CXX=g++" "LD=/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/libexec/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/ld" "NM=/usr/bin/nm" "RANLIB=ranlib" "DESTDIR=" all-recursive
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `HD/Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/missing --run makeinfo '.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As you can see it's truncating the Macintosh HD part of the path.  I tried running the full command above but editing the path, and its not helping...  Ideas?

Comment: A pragmatic solution might be to rename your hard disk - you could even use an ironic name like "C", or anything else you like, so long as it does not contain any spaces or other special characters.

Comment: I tried renaming and things started blowing up, got message about not finding my home directory, broken synlinks, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/...` bit is also known as `/Users/...` ?
If so,

```
$ ls -id "/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users"
$ ls -id /Users
```

should both give the same result, and you can just use the version with no space rather than fiddling about trying to quote it.

Comment: That sounds like a plan but how to I update the make to use the new path?  I tried adding a MAKEINFO to both the make and the make install but I get: /Volumes/Macintosh: /Volumes/Macintosh: is a directory
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 126
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Comment: I have no idea how this particular Makefile configures itself - you may just have to read it and see where the path is deduced.  If you previously ran `./configure` or similar, see if there are any arguments you can pass to that.

Comment: I've tried all the aguments I can think of, it still refuses to use the paths provided.  I'm out of ideas

Comment: Is this the thing you're trying to compile? I can't even see a Makefile in there ... https://github.com/ffi/ffi

Comment: Yes that's the project...  It's the last file in the list...  Thanks for helping!

Comment: So you're actually running `make -f ruby-ffi-Makefile.mk` or something similar?  If so, take a look at the Makefile fragments in nbproject, I can see `pwd` is run [here](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/master/nbproject/Makefile-variables.mk), and that's probably the root cause. Try substituting the correct value instead of shelling out to `pwd`.  You can figure out how to fix the Makefile after if you really want to.